# Exponential Taylor series with $k$ step

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

It is well-known that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = e ^x$$ or
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \cosh x $$

My question is what we know about the sum for arbitrary $k \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!} = ? $$

Are there any results (explicit functions, bounds, orders)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!}$$ is the uniques solution to the differential equation $$\frac{d^{k}}{dx^k}y-y=0\quad\quad y(0)=1,\quad\quad y^{(j)}(0)=0\;\;\forall 1\leq j<k.$$ A general solution to the ODE is $$y(x)=\sum_{j=1}^k c_j e^{r^j_kx},$$ where $r_k$ is the complex number given in polar form by $e^{2\pi i/k} $, and $c_j$ are constants. To fit initial conditions, we must have that $\sum_{j=1}^k c_j=1$, and $\sum_{j=1}^k c_jr^{jl}_k=0$ for $1<l<k$. Since $\sum_{j=1}^k r^{jl}_k=0$, the solution is to have $c_j=1/k$. Thus, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k e^{r^j_kx}.$$

Comment: Concise and complete.  Well done Alex!  +1 ... -Mark

Answer (score 3):

If $\zeta$ is a primitive $k$th root of unity, then
$$ x^n+(\zeta x)^n+\dots+(\zeta^{k-1}x)^n=x^n\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\zeta^{jn}=x^n\frac{1-\zeta^{kn}}{1-\zeta}=0 $$
provided that $k$ does not divide $n$. If $k$ does divide $n$, then the sum is just $kx^n$. Therefore
$$ \frac{e^x+e^{\zeta x}+\dots+e^{\zeta^{k-1}x}}{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!}$$